# Path is not a legal Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I get an error saying:"Path is not a legal form" at the line:

`fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`

Here is my code:

```
 private void Browse_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resDialog = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileBrowseBox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }


            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  // Stop watching
            fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(FileBrowseBox.Text);         // Text of textBox2 = Path of fileSystemWatcher2
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   // Begin watching

    }

    private void Browse_destination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  // Stop watching
            fileSystemWatcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            DestinationBox.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
            fileSystemWatcher2.Path = DestinationBox.Text;
            fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   // Begin watching
        }
    }
```

This is the DestinationBox.Text

I need it to transfer a file to it but i also wanna filewatch in it what happens
I Solved it with FileSystemWatcher2 but still gives me an error at FileSystemWatcher1
[image]

Comment: And what is the value of the `DestinationBox.Text`?

Comment: Please post only relevant code here. Dumping all the code made confusion for us

Comment: @SWekoThe Destination where the file should transfer

Comment: @sachin ok sorry i'll edit it.

Comment: Can you show an example of actual value of `DestinationBox.Text`?

Comment: Do you mean to use the value from `dlgOpenDir` not `DestinationBox`?

Comment: @loko DestinationBox.Text must be wrong (i.e. it doesn't specify an existing folder). Put `Trace.Assert(Directory.Exists(DestinationBox.Text));` just before the line that says `fileSystemWatcher2.Path = DestinationBox.Text;` to see if that's the case.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The name 'Trace' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Yuck what do you mean? :$ Give me an example of how you should do it in my code

Comment: @Ioko You need to add `using System.Diagnostics;` to use `Trace.Assert()`. Its only purpose is to show an error if the assertion fails.

Comment: empty string is not a valid path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the path selected by `dlgOpenDir` (presumably a [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)). Try this instead:

```
if (dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  // Stop watching
    fileSystemWatcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    fileSystemWatcher2.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
    fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   // Begin watching
}
```

Or, if you really want to show the folder that's being watched you could do this:

```
if (dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  // Stop watching
    fileSystemWatcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    DestinationBox.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
    fileSystemWatcher2.Path = DestinationBox.Text;
    fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   // Begin watching
}
```

Comment: When i browse for a file and click:"Cancel" it still gives me the error:"Path is not a legal form" but this time at the FileSystemWatcher1